# windows 11: how to display on the desktop just the folder and icons of choice?

Tags: windows, windows-11, desktop

Having the desktop of my windows 11 PC full of folder and file icons I would like to know if it is possible (with a free app or other way) to make visible only the ones I choose; all the available ones of the desktop should be accessible via windows explorer as it is currently.

Comment: It is not possible for a shortcut to exist within the Desktop folder and have it NOT appear on the Desktop. My suggestion, use the Start Menu, instead of adding shortcuts to every application on your system to your desktop.

Comment: @Ramhound do you guess that could be a new feature to suggest to Microsoft?

Comment: Are you asking if you can provide feedback to Microsoft?  Microsoft does have a way to collect this sort of feedback.  However, the Windows Desktop, has not really changed in decades.

Comment: You could hide the files/directories via the hidden attribute _(they'd still be visible in Explorer if "Show hidden files" is enabled)_, otherwise Stardock's [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) could be used

Comment: @JW0914, it is not free as requested in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your desktop is over-cluttered and you're looking for
a solution which is free and doesn't itself take much space on the desktop.

You may use the free keyboard macro
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).
For example, the following script will assign the shortcut Win+W to
running Wordpad: `#w::Run Wordpad`.

If you're looking for a free desktop organizer that is an
[alternative to Stardock Fences](https://alternativeto.net/software/fences/?license=free&platform=windows).

Here are a few :

- [iTop Easy Desktop Free](https://www.itopvpn.com/itop-easy-desktop)
- [SideSlide](https://www.northglide.com/sideslide.html)
- [TopTabs](https://www.rodo.casa/toptabs)